# Directory mounted under regular user is inaccessible from said user

Tags: rhel, sshfs

I have Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.5 and I just mounted an SSHFS directory. When I try to browse the mount as my regular user I can't browse it, but as root I can. Believing it was a problem with the UID under which the directory is mounted I listed the mount directory's permissions... and this is what I get.

```
[root@oc2222167007 sshfs]# ll
drwxr-xr-x. 1 nekomikoreimu daemon 4096 Jan 14 10:52 cogfvt1
[root@oc2222167007 sshfs]# exit
[nekomikoreimu@oc2222167007 sshfs]$ ll
ls: cannot access cogfvt1: Permission denied
d?????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? cogfvt1
```

Why can't I read the directory as user `nekomikoreimu` when listing it as root clearly says this user is the owner?

Comment: I am not really familiar with sshfs but since ssh itself is in the mix, it is helpful, if not mandatory to check the ownership permissions of .ssh directory and its contents. `ls -ld ~/.ssh`  and `ls -l ~/.ssh` outputs may give some useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after perusing the manpages looking for how to change the remote port to connect to a virtual machine... I found the answer.

All I had to do was adding `-o allow_other` and bam, it worked. Apparently, sshfs assumes you will read the mounted directory under the same user used to mount it, without considering that usually only ROOT is allowed to mount filesystems .-.